# Is it possible to access an extension function written for TextView with Databinding in XML layout?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, kotlin-android-extensions

my extension function for TextView:

```
fun TextView.setColorifiedText(text : String) {
 // Some logic to change color of text
 setText(text)
}
```

my xml file with databinding:

```
<layout>
   <data>
      <!--some data-->
   </data>
   <LinearLayout>
      <TextView 
        android:setColorifiedText="some text to be colorified"
      />
   </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: It is not supported. You can create a custom binding adapter and adapter pointing to extenstion function.

Comment: Or, if you make the extension function *be* a binding adapter function, it is supposed to work. I haven't tried it yet, but Yiğit mentioned it in the "fireside chat" session at the 2018 Android Developer Summit. Since extension functions are implemented as `static` Java methods (for Kotlin/JVM), apparently adding the `@BindingAdapter` annotation was sufficient for it to "just work".

Comment: as @CommonsWare mentions, if you annotate the method with `@BindingAdapter("android:setColorifiedText")`, then you can use it in xml as ` android:setColorifiedText="@{some text to be colorified}"` (one note though, if you use custom binding adapters, I'd have prefix `app:`, so it doesn't clash with android's setters)

Comment: @CommonsWare I annotated the method with \@BindingAdapter and I am getting an error stating: {****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:setColorifiedText' with parameter type androidx.lifecycle.LiveData<java.lang.String> on android.widget.TextView.}

Comment: Like I said, I haven't tried it yet. Watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FV3iN4PIB5U) -- Yiğit's remarks are somewhere around the 45:00 mark.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for suggesting the video. I found a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to access an extension function written for a view in XML.

We have prefix the extension function name with 'set' and annotate it with 'BindingAdapter' annotation., for ex:-
if your extension function name is 'colorText' change it to 'setColorText' and access the same in XML with the attribute name 'colorText' from 'app:' namespace.
Also, annotate the extension function with @BindingAdapter("colorText")

```
@BindingAdapter("colorText")
fun TextView.setColorText(text : String) {
   // logic to something with the text
}
```

in XML :

```
<TextView
   app:colorText="your String" />
```

you can also modify the code using the kotlin's setter getter to advantage

In case of java declare the function as static and add an argument to the method which gets reference to the textview you gave the attribute to.

Comment: i tried this but didn't work can you share how you achieve this with more code

Comment: @Bali Can you share your code... code I shared above is straight forward

Comment: I created an Activity class and added your extension function then i enabled data binding in build.gradle and finally i wrapped my xml under <layout tag then i tried to access "colorTex"t="your string" and it didn't work

Comment: @Bali what is the logic you used in the extension function.

Comment: I just added a log to see if it was being called and it wasn't